# Taylor Rule Model Specification: Serial Correlation and Interest Rate Smoothing

Tags: econometrics, monetary-policy, federal-reserve, fed-funds-rate

I'm reading [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11127-006-9017-0?error=cookies_not_supported&code=7b1c16bc-f7a8-4743-878d-d8342cfdd0c2) by Abrams and Iossifov. The paper investigates electoral cycles influence on monetary policy by estimating a Taylor Rule reaction function using OLS. The authors describe the methodology as follows:

> As an initial step in searching for a PMC, we estimate a number of
> Taylor- type equations for the period 1957–2004 using OLS and White
> correction for heteroskedasticity. Our dependent variable is the
> quarterly average for the Federal Funds Rate, FFRt .6 Explanatory
> variables initially include the quarter’s inﬂation rate (Inﬂationt)
> and the output gap (RgdpGapt). The FFR lagged one quarter, FFR(−1),
> enters the models as a RHS variable to allow interest-rate smoothing
> behavior by the Fed. It is expected that the signs on Inﬂation and
> RgdpGap are positive as both higher inﬂation rates and higher output
> gaps (i.e., real output above potential real GDP) are expected to en-
> courage monetary tightening by the Fed (i.e., the setting of higher
> rates for FFR). The ﬁndings for this equation speciﬁcation appear in
> model 1, Table 1. The Durbin h-test indicates the presence of serial
> correlation, so model 2 adds a ﬁrst-order autoregressive term, AR(1),
> to correct for this. We use model 2 as the baseline OLS model for the
> preliminary testing of propositions concerning the existence of a
> PMC.

I am confused by the difference between the FFR(-1) term used to account for interest rate smoothing and the AR(1) term used to correct for serial correlation. Is not the AR(1) term the same as the FFR(-1) term, and would not including them both in the model introduce perfect multicollinearity?

Thanks